# Silverlight DataGrid - LoadingRowDetails event

Tags: c#, silverlight

My DataGrid's `ItemsSource` is binding to `List<Pensioner>`. 
`Pensioner` is the class.

If I want to get `Selected` row with this code:

```
Pensioner pen = dataGridPens.SelectedItem as Pensioner;
```

it always gives me previous selected row.
I dont know why?

i am catching SelectedIndex on LoadingRowDetails  event.
But actaully this event is firing before SelectionChanged event. So the main problem is it.

Comment: If you bind the SelectedItem property to your MVVM Pensioner property in xaml, that code won't be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

On what event are you catching the SelectedItem, you will have the selected item for sure on SelectionChanged event.